# How to sort table by value and then print index in order

Tags: lua, lua-table

I would like to create a table `t` using the following format.

```
t[uniqueID] = order
```

The `uniqueID` will be unique but `order` can be either same or different each time.

And then I would like to sort the table in ascending order so I can print the `uniqueID` accordingly.

My Code:

```
t = {}

function compare(a, b)
    return a[2] < b[2]
end

function printid()
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        print(k)
    end
end

function main()
    t[5] = 47
    t[6] = 45
    t[7] = 49
    table.sort(t, compare)
    printid()
end
```

The result I get:

```
5
6
7
```

The result I expect:

```
6
5
7
```

How can I get the result I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From “Programming in Lua” section [19.3 “Sort”](https://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html).

> A common mistake is to try to order the indices of a table. In a table, the indices form a set, and have no order whatsoever.

That means you have to put the pairs of table `t` into another table `sorted` which then has contiguous indices.  This table can then be sorted based of the predicate you defined.  Furthermore you have to use `ipairs` when iterating a contiguously indexed table because in `pairs` the order is unspecified.

```
local t = {}

t[5] = 47
t[6] = 45
t[7] = 49

local sorted = {}
for k, v in pairs(t) do
    table.insert(sorted,{k,v})
end

table.sort(sorted, function(a,b) return a[2] < b[2] end)

for _, v in ipairs(sorted) do
    print(v[1],v[2])
end
```

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ab14kMgDHWL5uqvD)

Answer (score 2):

`pairs` [doesn't iterate in any particular order](https://lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next) (regardless of whether or not it's sorted).

`table.sort` only works on *lists* -- tables that use the keys `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, ..., `[#list]`.

---

You want a list of IDs in sorted order. This means

1. make a list of IDs
2. sort them by their associated values

In code,

```
local ids = {}

-- Order of insertion doesn't matter here since we will sort
for id in pairs(t) do
    table.insert(ids, id)
end

-- Sort the list of IDs by the values associated with each
table.sort(ids, function(a, b)
    return t[a] < t[b]
end)

for i = 1, #ids do
    print(ids[i])
end
--> 6
--> 5
--> 7
```